# masstransit publishfilter replace message

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

Does MassTransit allow to build a Publish Filter where it is possible to replace the original message with another message before sending?

We use MassTransit with Azure Service Bus. There are limits on max message size in Service Bus.
We discovered that some messages exceed the max message size limit.
To work around this, I would like to implement a publish filter. This filter would:

- put the message in a storage.
- replace the original message with an "empty" instance of the same type.
- send the replaced message instead of the original.

Then the consuming side would, upon receiving the message, try to retrieve the message body from storage by message id.

I tried to use `PublishContextProxy`, which allows passing the original context and a message, but this doesn't help, as the original message from the original context get published instead of the 'dummy' message I pass in constructor, e.g.

```
public class MyEventEventPublishFilter<T> : IFilter<PublishContext<T>>
where T : class 
{
    private readonly IStorageService _storage;

    public CampaignTraffickingEventPublishFilter(IStorageService storage)
    {
        _storage = storage;
    }

    public async Task Send(PublishContext<T> context, IPipe<PublishContext<T>> next)
    {
        if (context is PublishContext<MyBigEvent> { Message: var msg })
        {
            await _storageService.SetAsync(context.MessageId, evt);

            var newContext = new PublishContextProxy<MyBigEvent>(
                context,
                new MyBigEvent(evt.Id, null, null, 0, null, null, null, null)); // this attempts to replace the message
            await next.Send((newContext as PublishContextProxy<T>)!);
            evt.Fields = null;

            return;
        }

        await next.Send(context);
    }
```

}

This results in the original 'non-empty' message being published to the topic ...

Comment: Look at the [TransformFilter](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit/Middleware/TransformFilter.cs#L13) in MassTransit for some ideas. It's used by the Message Data (Claim Check) feature.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comment by Chris Patterson and after looking at [TransformFilter](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit/Middleware/TransformFilter.cs#L13),
the following implementation worked:

```
var newContext = context.CreateProxy(new MyBigEvent(evt.Id, null, null, 0, null, null, null, null));
```

This produces a new context with replaced message as expected.